# issues with probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

a man has $4$ children, given that **atleast one** of whom is a girl.Find the probability that he has $3$ girls and $1$ boy.

**MY TRY :**

probability of girl=$1/4$ and probability of boy=$3/4$ (my doubt is here, are these two probabiity correct? because it is said that `atleast one of whom is a girl` , not exactly 1)

=> 4c3 * (1/4)^4 * 3/4

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox

Comment: For each child, the probability of a boy = probability of a girl = 1/2.

Comment: do you have any problem understanding my solution?? @ritabrata Gautam??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that the following assumptions hold: each child is either male or female; each child has the same chance of being male as of being female; and the sex of each child is independent of the sex of the other.

If at least one of the four children is a girl, then there are 15 equally-likely possibilities: BBBG, BBGB, BBGG, BGBB, BGBG, BGGB, BGGG, GBBB, GBBG, GBGB, GBGG, GGBB, GGBG, GGGB, GGGG.  Of these, there are four equally-likely cases where he has 3 girls and 1 boy (BGGG, GBGG, GGBG, GGGB).  Thus, the probability that he has 3 girls and 1 boy given that he has at least 1 girl is 4/15.

Comment: why we need ordering?? BBBG, BBGB and BGBB are all same ....

Comment: The 15 possibilities I listed are all equally likely (assuming the probabilities of having a boy and of having a girl are the same).  The probability of having, say, four girls is not the same as the probability of having, say, three girls and one boy.

Comment: but all these BBBG, BBGB and BGBB refers to having 3 boys and 1 girl....so why we need all these case??

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche what is wrong in  joyentanuj das's procedure?

Comment: You can imagine the sample space of having four children as the set {four boys, three boys and one girl, two boys and two girls, one boy and three girls, four girls}.  But these events are not equally likely.  Would you say that the probability of having four girls is the same as the probability of having three girls and one boy?

Answer (score 1):

You can also see it like this. Define the events

- $A$ = at least one child is a girl
- $B$ = three children are girls and one is a boy

There are 16 cases in the whole, of which $15$ satisfy $A$ and $4$ satisfy $B$. Furthermore $B \cap A = B$.
Thus $p(A)=\frac{15}{16}$ and $p(B)=\frac{4}{16}$, and $$p(B|A)=\frac{p(B \cap A )}{p(A)}=\frac{p(B)}{p(A)}=\frac{4}{15}.$$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to mention that in this case $B \cap A = B$. It might be $B|A$ instead of $A|B$, it is just a matter of how you write "the event $B$ given the event $A$". It's a convention. But my formula is right, and by the way it confirms your result.

Answer (score 0):

I would condition on all the possible # of girls:

$P(3G & 1B)= 
P(2G & 1B among three children|#G=1)P(#G=1)+
+P(1G & 1B among two children| #G=2)P(#G=2) +
+P( 1B  the fourth children |#G=3 )P(#G=3) +
+P(-1G |#G=4)P(#G=4)$

the last term is zero because if he has four girls he can't have a boy

$P(#G=1)=1$

$P(#G=2)=Bin(n=3,k=1,p=1/2)$

$P(#G=3)=Bin(n=3,k=2,p=1/2)$

$P(2G & 1B among three children|#G=1)= Bin(n=3,k=2,p=1/2)$

$P(1G & 1B among two children| #G=2)= Bin(n=2,k=1,p=1/2)$

$P( 1B  the fourth children |#G=3 )=1/2$

Answer (score -1):

The man has four children of which have have atleast one girl so he may have 1 girl and three boys or two girls and two boys or three girls and one boy or four girls. so the probability that he has 3 girls and one boy is 1/4.

Comment: do you have any problem understanding my solution?? @ritabrata Gautam??

Comment: as joel mentioned according to your solution `the probability of having four girls is the same as the probability of having three girls and one boy`